# What events are triggered when calling fetch() on a Backbone.js collection?

Tags: backbone.js

In my backbone.js app, there is a `Trips collection` that holds `Trip models`, which is working with `LocalStorage`. I am able to call `Trips.create(form_attributes)` to create and save a trip to the `Todos store`.

When I first load my app, I call `Trips.fetch({ success: trips_fetch_success })`, and `trips_fetch_success` receives a response that shows the `Trip models` that the `Trips collection` holds.

I have tried to bind `refresh` and `change` events to the `Trips collection`, but these events are not being caught, making me believe I have the wrong idea about which events `Trips.fetch` triggers.

My question: which events should `Trips.fetch` trigger? And are the events triggered on the collection or on each of the individual `Trip models`?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`Collection.fetch()` will call `reset` on success, which in turn will trigger a 'reset' event.  Any subscribers to the collections reset event should receive the event.

The key here is "on success."  I had this problem, only to discover that backbone was silently swallowing my errors messages.  Pass in an error handler that, at least, logs to `console.log()`, and see what's happening:

```
trips.fetch({error: function() { console.log(arguments); }});
```

(Note: Old versions of backbone.js will trigger "refresh" instead of "reset")

Comment: You can have a global jQuery ajax error handler to handle errors of this kind, usually related to connectivity issues.

Comment: As of backbone 0.5+, `Collection#refresh` [was renamed](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#changelog) to `Collection#reset`. The event is also renamed accordingly.

Comment: Also, useful to know that the `reset` callback has two default arguments `"reset" (collection, options)` and it is triggered when the collection's entire contents have been replaced.`

Answer (score 52):

If you are using backbone 1.0, you'll need to pass reset:true in the fetch() call in order to bind with the reset event:

```
trips.fetch({reset: true});
```

Comment: good point.  When I wish to refresh a view based on a model fetch(), I bind to 'sync'.  That's what is triggered by default in 1.0.

Answer (score 20):

As of backbone 1.0, model.fetch() triggers a 'sync'.  That's what you should bind to.

Here's the relevant part from the backbone.js source where the 'sync' event is fired:

```
fetch: function(options) {
  options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
  if (options.parse === void 0) options.parse = true;
  var model = this;
  var success = options.success;
  options.success = function(resp) {
    if (!model.set(model.parse(resp, options), options)) return false;
    if (success) success(model, resp, options);

    // HERE'S THE TRIGGER!
    model.trigger('sync', model, resp, options);

  };
  wrapError(this, options);
  return this.sync('read', this, options);
},
```

Comment: that's the actual code from the backbone.js source, btw.  I just re-read my comment and wondered what the code was myself...  Better to be explicit.