# Backbone fetch success callback

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to backbone.js and I'm having some issues with giving my collection a success callback. I'm overriding fetch in order to have a url with a parameter in it. As I understand it I should be able to assign a success callback in the options I pass to Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call()... but, my code isn't working. Fetch works correctly, but the callback function is not called.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
App.ChartController = {
  load: function(userConceptId) {
    App.chartPointList.fetch(userConceptId);    
  }
};


App.ChartPointList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: App.ChartPoint,
  url: function() {
    return '/chartpoints/' + this.userConceptId;
  },
  fetch: function(userConceptId, options) {         
    console.log("fetch chart point");               

    typeof(options) != 'undefined' || (options = {});
    options.success = this.postProcess;
    options.error = this.handleError;

    this.userConceptId = userConceptId;

    return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);    
  },
  postProcess : function (resp, status, xhr) {
    console.log("postprocess");          // never gets called
    /**
     ... whole bunch of stuff... 
    **/
    new App.Views.ChartView({ collection: this });
  }, 
  handleError : function (resp, status, xhr) {
    alert("could not load chart data!");  // also not called
  }
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The _error callback_ works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/vsZUD/ , so the problem should be somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

@fguillen's comment and [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264247/what-events-are-triggered-when-calling-fetch-on-a-backbone-js-model) helped me figure this out. Specifically:

> Collection.fetch() will call reset() on success, which in turn will trigger a 'reset' event. Any subscribers to the collections reset event should receive the event.

The issue wasn't with my success callback at all. Turns out I had an problem in a view that was subscribed to the ChartPointList reset event. A function in that view was being called *before* the success callback and throwing an error, and thus the success callback was not being called.

Comment: Awesome — listening to "reset" works perfectly.
Also [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659283/backbone-js-fetch-with-parameters) helped me pass parameters to specific fetch without modifying the collection's url or fetch.