# Backbone Paginator Collection not triggering render on Reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a Backbone Paginator Collection:

```
    var ExercisesCollection = Backbone.Paginator.requestPager.extend({

        model: ExerciseModel,

        paginator_core: {
            url: "/exercises"
        },

        paginator_ui: {
            firstPage: 1,
            currentPage: 1,
            perPage: 10,
            totalPages: 10
        },

        server_api: {
            "filter": "",
            "categories": "",
            "top": function() { return this.perPage; },
            "skip": function() { return this.currentPage * this.perPage; }
        },

        parse: function (response) {
            this.totalPages = response.meta.totalPages;
            return response.data;
        }

    });
```

I use it in a Backbone View like so:

```
var Exercises = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new ExercisesCollection();
        this.collection
            .on( "reset", this.render, this )
            .on( "change", this.render, this);
        this.collection.goTo( 1 );
    },

    render: function() {
        alert("bah!");
    }
});
```

By looking at the network activity, I can see that it is sending the request to the server and receiving an appropriate response.  However it never calls the render function.  The reset and change events do not seem to be working.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: this.collection there do you define it?

Comment: Yes this.collection is an instance of the Paginator Collection

Comment: .on( "add", this.render, this ) ?

Comment: Tried it - Unfortunately no.

Comment: I dont familiar with Backbone.Paginator, can you test this with normal backbone collection?

Comment: Yes it seems to work with a normal collection - so I am thinking it must have something to do with Paginator, and the way I'm handling it.

Comment: this.collection = (new ExercisesCollection()).paginatedItems

Comment: check source code of http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone.paginator/examples/netflix-request-paging/index.html

Comment: Try this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in 2016 :)
When you're using the `'server'` mode, you need to listen to the `'sync'` event, not `'reset'`.

```
// in a view
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.renderPage);
```

From backbone docs (http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch):

> When the model data returns from the server, it uses set to
>   (intelligently) merge the fetched models, unless you pass {reset:
>   true}, in which case the collection will be (efficiently) reset.

So it doesn't call `reset()` by default, and so no `'reset'` event.

I have found out about the `'sync'` event in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17053978/1657101

> As of backbone 1.0, model.fetch() triggers a 'sync'. That's what you should bind to.